# Reset topic published by plugin while resettin simulation

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
this is a follow-up to [this question](https://answers.ros.org/question/282565/force-torque-sensor-stops-publishing/). Is there a way (in python?) to reset the topic published by force_torque sensor included in urdf, or, for example joint_states topic to base values right before the simulation resets?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282911/reset-topic-published-by-plugin-while-resettin-simulation/) by [Fiddle](https://answers.ros.org/users/32064/fiddle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 64 on 2018-02-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-19**:
@Fiddle: I have to ask you to please stop bumping your question. If you haven't received any answers that means either no one knows, or board members that do know just haven't read your question yet.

**Comment by [Fiddle](https://answers.ros.org/users/32064/fiddle/) on 2018-02-19**:
Sorry for bumping this question, anyway, I've found solution to the previous question, so this one might as well be closed

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-19**:
I would just post an answer yourself, pointing to either the issue you link in your other question, or only referring to your other question. Then accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since I figured out a question to the [previous problem](https://answers.ros.org/question/282565/force-torque-sensor-stops-publishing/) I no longer need to set the header parameters, since they started to reset normally.

---

Originally posted by [Fiddle](https://answers.ros.org/users/32064/fiddle/) with karma: 64 on 2018-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0